# Looking for an opposite to "sacrifice" (n.) in a specific context

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm looking for a word or phrase with an opposite meaning to "sacrifice", as used below:

"They *had to make sacrifices* in order for us to meet the deadline, since the recent event reduced their productivity.  This same event actually boosted my own productivity, so I *[was able to retain some personal resources that I would have ordinarily expended]*

Best I could come up with is "enjoyed luxuries", but I feel like there's a better alternative.

Comment: _reaped a bountiful harvest_?

Comment: *profited from their loss*, *was rewarded for their hard work*, *gained at their expense*, ...

Comment: There are various shades of meaning in what you could say: are you getting richer, living more luxuriously, being free from poverty and worry, eating better, enjoying life, celebrating, partying, going out more, throwing around your money, distributing largesse, enjoying a better lifestyle, living comfortably, moving up in the world, getting fat, becoming decadent...

Comment: Thrived despite the schadenfreude.

Comment: *They made sacrifices while I made bank.*

Comment: This same event actually proved a boon to me by boosting my own productivity.

Comment: The opposite of _they had to make sacrifices_ is _they didn't have to make sacrifices_. There isn't a special verb for it.

Comment: Can you not try three or four re-phrasings of 'They had to make sacrifices…'? I cut the passage there because all the rest seemed extraneous, confusing and as such, downright unhelpful.

Comment: *Chillax*, *crack open some brewskis*, *make hay*... Really depends on the tone you're going for.

Comment: An [unexpected] bonus.

Answer (score 1):

"Profited", "pocketed" and "raked it in" will all work well.

- They had to make sacrifices, while I profited.
- They had to make sacrifices, while I pocketed the fruit of their sacrifices.
- They had to make sacrifices, they had to endure losses, while I raked in the profits.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.  Please give additional information as to how these phrases answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Lived high on the hog**
To prosper or otherwise live very well. It refers to the rich being able to afford the choicest cut of meat, which, from a pig, is higher up on the animal.

*They've been living high on the hog ever since David won the lottery.

It must be a shock for them having to count their pennies like this—they're used to living high on the hog, after all.*

https://www.lexico.com/definition/live_high_on_the_hog

Answer (score 0):

> "They had to make sacrifices in order for us to meet the deadline,

They had to be **extravagant** in order for us to meet the deadline.

OED

> **7. Exceeding the bounds of economy or necessity in expenditure, mode of living, etc.; profuse, prodigal, wasteful.**
>
> **a. Of persons.**
>
> 1711   J. Addison Spectator No. 243. ¶8   An extravagant Man..has
> nothing else to recommend him but a false Generosity.
>
> 1814   J. Austen Mansfield Park I. ii. 39   His eldest son was careless and extravagant.
>
> 1879   J. A. Froude Cæsar i. 6   The rich were extravagant, for life had ceased to have practical interest, except for its material pleasures.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's example makes it clear that what the question seeks is the **gradable** antonym for *sacrifice*, i.e. the term for something that stands on the opposite end of the spectrum whose other end is occupied by *sacrifice*. Now, to say that somebody made a sacrifice means that the person incurred some major **cost**, a cost that far exceeds those that are normally expected to be incurred in the course of the activity in question (using *cost* here in the broad sense that is not limited to monetary costs). Thus, when we read in the OP's example that 'they had to make sacrifices in order for us to meet the deadline', that conveys the idea that they did something like working overtime for many hours (and not just that they had to do some work to meet the deadline).

The opposite of *cost* is *benefit*, so the opposite (of the kind that is indicated by the OP's example) of

> a cost that far exceeds those that are normally expected to be incurred in the course of the activity in question (i.e. a sacrifice)

is

> a benefit that far exceeds those that are normally expected to be incurred in the course of the activity in question.

At least one term for such a benefit is ***windfall***.

As *windfall* is usually used for economic benefits, when it is used, as a redily understood metaphor, for noneconomic benefits, it may be wise to specify what they are. Thus, in the OP's example, one may want to say

> . . . so I received a windfall of leisure.